# Drawing control-theory block diagrams with Doxygen

Tags: c++, latex, doxygen

I'm working on a C++ project in the field of automatics I'd like to start documenting. I'm rather decided for Doxygen. But, apart of documenting particular fields of data and drawing class-hierarchy UML-diagrams, I'd like to document several methods' functionalities with block diagrams like this one:
[image]

What are the solutions?

I'm familiar with LaTeX. I've read Doxygen has some support for LaTeX, I don't know how far this goes, though. Is it possible to use any LaTeX package within Doxygen? Which particular packages would you recommend and could you provide some simple examples as well?

I'm also open to recommendations of something different than Doxygen.

Comment: If you want to do it in LaTeX you can do diagrams just like the one above in TikZ. If that is your interest either flag for migrations to http://tex.stackexchange.com or search it for similar questions.

Comment: I think Doxygen's LaTeX support is more about entering math formula, and perhaps GraphViz is more suitable here (disclaimer: I do not use Doxygen, nor familiar with it).

Comment: That looks very interesting. I have made a tool that generates code from a visual representation. http://memention.com/designer/ I'd love to hear what you think.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I eventually started learning TikZ, which seems to have tremendous possibilities. I also read about the dot language, which is supported by Doxygen, but I think it's only suitable for drawing graphs rather than block diagrams.

Answer (score 2):

If it's only about getting the control-systems structure, variables etc. documented you can generate the diagram elsewhere (e.g. Dia, XFig or Inkscape if you want to use open source tools) and embed them into your Doxygen documentation via the image keyword from within your code:

```
/*!
.. Doxygen doc here..
\image html Data_Model.png "Figure 1: UML Diagram of the Data Source and Data Model Relationships"
*/
```

To do this you'll need to tell Doxygen in the **Doxyfile** file where to find the images, and place the images relative to your doxygen path (DOCROOT/images in this case):

```
# The IMAGE_PATH tag can be used to specify one or more files or 
# directories that contain image that are included in the documentation (see 
# the \image command).

IMAGE_PATH             = images
```

Using latex extensions or other language driven graphical markups for generating graphs from within Doxygen doc does imho not justify the overhead of learning the language, getting the tool-chain configured and aligned. On the other hand if you have some tool already which is generating the graph automatically (from your code or a config file), it should be a breeze to run the tool from within a Makefile, let it generate the image and embed the image in your doxygen doc via the image keyword.